# Meteor user has no email address

Tags: meteor, schema, meteor-accounts

Using [simple schema](https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-simple-schema) and [accounts-password](https://www.meteor.com/accounts). I'm trying to add in an initial account on start-up, but the email and password are not appearing.

```
Schemas.User = new SimpleSchema({
  username: {
    type: String,
    regEx: /^[a-z0-9A-Z_]{3,15}$/
  },
  emails: {
    type: [Object],
    optional: true
  },
  "emails.$.address": {
    type: String,
    regEx: SimpleSchema.RegEx.Email
  },
  "emails.$.verified": {
    type: Boolean
  },
  profile: {
    type: Schemas.UserProfile,
    optional: true
  }
});
```

and

```
Meteor.startup(function () {
  Meteor.users.remove({});
  if (Meteor.users.find().count() == 0) {
    Accounts.createUser({
      username: "newuser",
      emails: [{address:"test@test.com", verified:true}],
      password:"mypassword"
    });
  }
  console.log(Meteor.users.find().fetch());
}
```

Gives us:

```
[{_id: 'xxx', username:'newuser'}]
```

No email or password. No errors. Thoughts?

New users in this system can only be added by existing users, so I haven't been able to test the user submission form.

Comment: [Accounts.createUser](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/accounts_createuser) takes a `String` as a second parameter, not an array. Just give it the email as a string and validate it afterwards.

Comment: Sorry, not parameter, `email` property for the `options` parameter

Comment: @BraveKenny that worked for the email, but now I'm getting "no password set" error attempting to log in

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Accounts.createUser](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/accounts_createuser) takes a String as an `email` property for the `options` parameter. As for the password problem, it is maybe due to the lack of a `services` property in your schema. Add to your `Schemas.User` the following property:

```
Schemas.User = new SimpleSchema({
  // ...
  services: {
      type: Object,
      optional: true,
      blackbox: true
  }
}
```

Finally, the `Accounts.createUser` documentation (see first link) states:

> On the client, you must pass password and at least one of `username` or `email` — enough information for the user to be able to log in again later. On the server, you do not need to specify password, but the user will not be able to log in until it has a password (eg, set with `Accounts.setPassword`).

It seems to not apply in your case, but as a last resort, try to call `Accounts.setPassword(userId, "mypassword")` afterwards. The user's id is returned by `Meteor.createUser`.

Comment: Error: services.password.srp is not allowed by the schema